# Group Collection of Items by Category in ListView

Tags: wpf, listview, collections

I have a Collection of Items. `ObservableCollection<Channel> Channels;`

Each `Channel` contains **Name** and **Category** Properties. I want to display this collection in a `ListView`. Also, I want to Click on **Category** expander and then show channels list with channel's name.

Can you give me some advice?

Answer (score 1):

Make a DataTemplate for a single Channel:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ChannelTemplate">
    <Expander Header="{Binding Name}">
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding CategoryProperties}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding prop1}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding prop2}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </ListBox>
    </Expander>
</DataTemplate>
```

And then use it in a ListBox/View:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Channels}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ChannelTemplate}" />
```

This assumes that you set the DataContext property of the Window/UserControl to an object that contains a property named Channels.

**EDIT**

You might also want to take a [look at CollectionViewSource to use the built-in grouping](http://www.wpftutorial.net/dataviews.html#grouping).

Comment: Please be more specific. I might have made some errors. Did you put the DataTemplate in a the Window's/UserControl's Resources? My assumptions about your code might be wrong too (stuff like CategoryProperties )

Answer (score 0):

You can try looking over this sample: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms771309(v=VS.90).aspx, which I think should give you some clarity on how to proceed.